# how to find The median of a Grouped data when the sum of the frequency is odd?

Tags: statistics, median

how to find The median of a Grouped data when the sum of the frequency is odd? Can anyone explain me with an example. I have searched a lot. But each example in the internet is done with even number. I want to know what to do for the case of odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is useful to identify the *interval* that contains the median, and that
can be done without making unwarranted assumptions. For example, consider the
$n = 25$ scores below, which have been sorted from smallest to largest.

```
 75    76    80    82    88    90    91    92    94    95
 99   100   102   103   103   105   106   107   109   113   
113   115   116   116   119
```

Their exact median is $H = 102,$ the thirteenth observation in the sorted list.

A frequency histogram below based on the following cutpoints (bin boundaries):

```
74.5, 84.5, ..., 114.5, 125.5.
```

These boundaries were chosen so that no (integer) score can fall exactly
on a boundary.

The five interval midpoints are 79.5, 89.5, 99.5, 109.5, and 119.5. We can see
from this frequency histogram below, that the corresponding frequencies
are 4, 5, 6, 6, and 4.

Just looking at the histogram (or at a table of interval boundaries, midpoints,
and frequencies), and *without knowledge* of the exact values of the $n = 25$
observations, all we can say about the median is that it falls in the
interval $(94.5, 104.5)$ with midpoint $99.5$ and frequency $6.$ This
interval is called the *median interval.*

In practice, grouped data tables and histograms are used mainly for samples
that are at least moderately large. For a large sample it would ordinarily
be sufficient to say that the median falls in the interval with midpoint $99.5.$

[image]

A favorite exercise in elementary statistics books is to try to approximate the
exact value of the median from a histogram or from grouped data. Doing so
requires one to make the assumption (seldom true) that the observations within the median
interval are evenly spaced (or uniformly distributed).

One formula for approximating the exact median $H$ is

$$ H = L + \frac{w}{f_m}(.5n - cf_b),$$

where $L = 94.5$ is the lower limit of the median interval, $f_m = 6$ is the
frequency of the median interval, $cf_b = 9$ is the number of observations
in intervals below the median interval, $w = 10$ is the (common) interval
width, and $n = 25$ is the total sample size. This kind of formula is
sometimes called an 'interpolation' formula.

For our data,

$$ H = 94.5 + (10/6)(25/2 - 9) = 100.3333.$$

This procedure is seldom used in serious statistical analysis, and formulas
for it can differ a bit from one textbook to another. I do not know the formula in
your book, or why you wonder about a distinction between even and odd
sample sizes $n$.

I hope this answer is helpful. If you are using a different formula to
approximate the median, or if you have further questions, please leave me a Comment and edit your
Question to be a little more specific. Then perhaps one of us can be of
further help.

*Notes*: (1) The 25 observations are simulated from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 100,\,\sigma = 15)$ and rounded to integers. So the median of the *population* from which
the data were drawn is $\eta = 100.$ (2) It is not usually a good idea to
'group' datasets with $n$ as small as 25, or to make histograms of such
small datasets. I chose this particular illustration because I thought it
would make the application of the interpolation formula easy to follow.

Comment: **Addendum:** A more generally useful formula approximates the sample mean $\bar X$ from grouped data as $\bar X \approx (\sum_j f_jm_j)/(\sum_j f_j),$ where $m_j$ are class midpoints, $f_j$ are class frequencies, and sums are taken over all intervals. // This approximation arises from the assumption that all observations in class $i$ are located at $m_i.$ // For the example in my Answer the exact sample mean is 99.5, and this approximation formula gives 99.9. // The approximation tends to work best when the number of classes is large.